# Application.LoadLevel.. how to load more than 2 levels in a game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, loading

I am creating a game in which we hit the bricks from a Ball attached to the paddle,in order to clear those bricks and move to next level...
m doing like this

if bricks count comes to zero. level02 loaded.

```
void Die() {
    Destroy (gameObject);
    PaddleScript paddleScript = GameObject.Find("Paddle").GetComponent<PaddleScript> ();
    paddleScript.AddPoint(pointValue);
    numBricks--;
    if (numBricks<= 0 ){
        // load new level
        Application.LoadLevel("level02");
    }
 }
```

but how to load remaining next level if we able to clear all bricks of level02.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an empty game object for all your scenes and attach a script which has `loadlevel()` method.

eg:

```
public string levelName;

void Die() {
    Destroy (gameObject);
    PaddleScript paddleScript = GameObject.Find("Paddle").GetComponent<PaddleScript> ();
    paddleScript.AddPoint(pointValue);
    numBricks--;
    if (numBricks<= 0 ){
        // load new level
        Application.LoadLevel(levelName);
    }
 }
```

Now you have a script in every level that can load a level. From the editor change levelName field to suit the level as you need. If you are in `level01`, `levelName` to be loaded will be `level02` and on.